# Spring RESTful endpoint not asynchonous

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have an issue with an endpoint that is not behaving as I would expect. Basically, it follows the flow the way I would expect and it hits the return statement BEFORE it fires the callback methods. So, all seems good.

However, when I test this in Postman, the method still hangs. It blocks and does not return a response until the callback onSuccess is executed. Is this how this should behave or am I missing something?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/async", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<String> createAsync(@RequestBody Input input) throws CombineException {

    AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
    DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(input , headers);

    ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<Input>> future = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/myLongRunningEndpointIDontWantToWaitFor", HttpMethod.POST, entity, Input.class);     
    future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<Input>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<Input> response) {
           System.out.println("Success");
           result.setResult(response.getBody().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
           System.out.println("FAILED");
           result.setErrorResult(t.getMessage());
        }
    });
    System.out.println("RETURNING...");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: could you clarify your question; from what you're reading, the Postman client is getting the response when you're sending it from the controller, as expected. Using a DefferredResult means that you're not blocking a container thread while processing the response; if you'd like to stream data to the client, then SSEEmitter might be a better fit.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the confusion. When I submit in postman, I guess I would have expected a 200 response to return back to the caller while the processing continues on the server. But postman just waits on the long running service to complete. I think I may just misunderstand how this works. The thread is freed to do other things, but the controller method won't actually return until all the work is done. Is that correct?

Comment: The server might write the response headers but you’re not guarantee to have those on the client side right away. It all depends if the server flushes and writes to the network. Otherwise your assumptions are correct.